# Jquery mobile: dynamic created checkbox should automatically move to next column

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have a textbox and a button in a page and once you enter a text and click on the button it should create a dynamic text box with the entered value in the textbox

How to create a maximum of 10 checkbox in rows and 5 checkbox in columns..After it reached 10 checkbox in rows,the next checkbox should start from next column.How can I achieve this please help..
Here is my coding..

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="txtName" />
    <center>
        <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inline ui-btn-b ui-icon-plus ui-btn-icon-left" id="btn1" data-role="button">Add</a>
    </center>
    <div id="cblist"></div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).on("pageinit","#pagetobringone",function(){
    $('#btn1').click(function() {
        addCheckbox($('#txtName').val());
    });
});


function addCheckbox(name) {
    var container = $('#cblist');
    var inputs = container.find('input');
    var id = inputs.length+1;

    $('<input />', { type: 'checkbox', id: 'cb'+id, value: name }).appendTo(container);
    $('<label />', { 'for': 'cb'+id, text: name }).appendTo(container);
}
```

Comment: Please note that `pageinit` is deprecated in favor of `pagecreate`. If you are using a recent version of jQuery Mobile, you should replace the deprecated API. http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecreate/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you could use an HTML `<table>` and create a new row every tenth checkbox. Put a table in your cblist container:

```
<div id="cblist">
    <table>
        <tbody></tbody>            
    </table>        
</div>
```

Then in the addCheckbox function, use the modulus.remainder **[operator](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp)** (%) to calculate when a new row is needed

```
function addCheckbox(name) {
    var container = $('#cblist');
    var inputs = container.find('input');
    var IsNewRow = inputs.length % 10 == 0;
    var id = inputs.length+1;
    if (id > 50) return;

    if (IsNewRow){
        //append new row every 10 checkboxes
        $('#cblist tbody').append("<tr></tr>");
    }
    //find last row in the table
    var $row = $('#cblist tbody tr:last-child')

    var $td = $('<td />');
    $('<input />', { type: 'checkbox', id: 'cb'+id, value: name }).appendTo($td);
    $('<label />', { 'for': 'cb'+id, text: name }).appendTo($td);
    $row.append($td);
    container.enhanceWithin();
}
```

> Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/k73hk1b3/3/)**

Comment: nice, sometimes i go the long way round :))

Comment: @Tasos, looks like we had about the same idea at the same time

Comment: we did actually, i completed the answer just when you posted. yours is better though. i never attempted this kind of question so i took the long way round. ill leave it in there anyway.

Comment: @Manikandan, Go ahead and ask.

Answer (score 1):

A checkbox or a textarea?? Question is not very clear. However both are easy and made a demo for you, it seems to do the job and has unique ids for the buttons and check or boxes if you want to grab the data

**Demo checkbox with submit button**

http://jsfiddle.net/dmbba978/

**Demo textarea with submit button**

http://jsfiddle.net/rvfrmas1/

**Demo textarea one buton**

http://jsfiddle.net/38Lf1xLL/

**Demo checkbox one buton**

http://jsfiddle.net/gvje5f4k/

```
var a = 1;
var b = 1;
var c = 1;
var pagedata = $('<td><textarea cols="10" rows="2" name="textarea-'+ c +'" id="textarea-1">Textarea</textarea> <input type="button" value="Submit" id="sub' + c +'"></td>');    

pagedata.appendTo("#form1");

$("#form1").enhanceWithin();

$(document).on( "click", "#sub1, #sub2,#sub3,#sub4,#sub5,#sub6,#sub7,#sub8,#sub9,#sub10,#sub11,#sub12,#sub13,#sub14,#sub15,#sub16,#sub17,#sub18,#sub19,#sub20,#sub21,#sub22,#sub23,#sub24,#sub25,#sub26,#sub27,#sub29,#sub30,#sub31,#sub32,#sub33,#sub34,#sub35,#sub38,#sub37,#sub39,#sub40,#sub41,#sub43,#sub43,#sub44,#sub45,#sub46,#sub47,#sub49,#sub50" , function( event ) {
c = c + 1;
    if (c < 51) {    
    if (b != 6 && a < 11) {
 if (a < 11) {

 a = a + 1;

var pagedata = $('<td><textarea cols="10" rows="2" name="textarea-'+ c +'" id="textarea-1">Textarea</textarea> <input type="button" value="Submit" id="sub' + c +'"></td>');    

 }

 if (a == 11) {

     b = b + 1;
     a = 1;
     var newrow = $('<tr id="form' + b +'"> </tr>');
       newrow.appendTo("#tab"); 

     var pagedata = $('<td><textarea cols="10" rows="2" name="textarea-'+ c +'" id="textarea-1">Textarea</textarea> <input type="button" value="Submit" id="sub' + c +'"></td>');     

    }

pagedata.appendTo("#form" + b);

$("#form" + b).enhanceWithin();

    }
    }
})
```